# Magento Patch SUPEE 8788 - 1.9.2.4 - uploaderSingle.swf

Tags: magento1.9.2.4, supee-8788

I'd like to be able to quickly and efficiently apply this patch to my 1.9.2.4 stores, however getting problems with the uploaderSingle.swf file

```
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf.rej
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

Considering it's meant to be deleting the file, bit of a pain.

Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: I have the same when I try to apply the patch on Windows via cygwin. Had to do it on a linux machine or remove the `uploaderSingle.swf` part of the patch and delete the file manually (which is what the patch tried and failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so zipping PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh and then uploading and then unzipping on the server seems to fix this issue.

Comment: Where can I actually find the ZIP version of this Magento patch? New Magento policy BTW?

Comment: Since the files have to be downloaded first locally, if you're PC based, then right clicking and send to zip should be enough

Comment: This does nothing

Comment: **I met the same problem in swf in 1.9.2.4.**

> Fox Fixed - Please follow below steps.
> 
> Step 1. Download security patch 8788 SSH file to this Link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
> 
> Step 2. After download security patch 8788 SSH file Please put into one folder and make same folder Zip file.
> 
> Step 3. Please upload Zip folder to root magento folder and Unzip through SSH Putty.
> 
> Step 4. Run the patch :-
$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem is solved more easily by downloading the patch file, zip it and upload it to the server. Then unzip it with SSH and apply the patch. Seems to be something with the binary data contained in the patch file.

Comment: Pretty sure that's what I've just said above :)

Comment: Almost, zipping the zip might confuse some peope. You actually download the .sh file, then zip it...

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see had managed to paste the .zip file instead of the .sh.

Comment: **I met the same problem in swf in 1.9.2.4.**

> Fox Fixed - Please follow below steps.
> 
> Step 1. Download security patch 8788 SSH file to this Link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
> 
> Step 2. After download security patch 8788 SSH file Please put into one folder and make same folder Zip file.
> 
> Step 3. Please upload Zip folder to root magento folder and Unzip through SSH Putty.
> 
> Step 4. Run the patch :-
$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh

Answer (score 0):

zipping file with windows jzip, then upload and linux command unzip and sh PATCH.... it works!