# SUPEE 8788 Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, magento1.9.2.4, supee-8788

Trying to apply this patch to a 1.9.2.4 site and getting errors. Have already managed this with other Magento versions, a few errors but nothing I can't fix.

Getting these errors:

```
patching file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 275.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 397.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml.rej
```

I've checked this file and it is identical to what the patch is expecting

```
patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf.rej

patching file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf.rej
```

This post ([Magento Patch SUPEE 8788 - 1.9.2.4 - uploaderSingle.swf](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140661/magento-patch-supee-8788-1-9-2-4-uploadersingle-swf)) suggesting zipping and unzipping the patch file, but this had no effect for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conflict happens in `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml`

Most likely this file is not the original file from 1.9.2.4 that's why the patch fails.

Here are the steps to take:

- backup this `app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml` file by renaming it
- download the original 1.9.2.4 file from here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.4/app/etc/modules/Mage_All.xml
- apply the patch
- compare the backup file and the new file to see what were your custom modifications (maybe you disabled a module in there) and reapply them.

Comment: **I met the same problem in swf in 1.9.2.4.**

> Fox Fixed - Please follow below steps.
> 
> Step 1. Download security patch 8788 SSH file to this Link :- https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
> 
> Step 2. After download security patch 8788 SSH file Please put into one folder and make same folder Zip file.
> 
> Step 3. Please upload Zip folder to root magento folder and Unzip through SSH Putty.
> 
> Step 4. Run the patch :-
$ bash PATCH_SUPEE-8788_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2016-10-11-07-03-46.sh